# How can I show complete graphs are determined by spectrum?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I understand how to prove a complete graph $K_n$ has spectrum $\lbrace -1^{(n-1)},n-1 \rbrace$. However I am having difficulty proving that the spectrum uniquely determines the complete graph.

Wolfram seems to suggest there is a simple proof, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeterminedbySpectrum.html .

Any ideas how to construct all graphs from these eigenvalues or prove this construction indirectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adjacency matrix of a complete graph is $J-I$ such that $J_{ij}=1$ for all $i,j$. Since J is symetric it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors (ie diagonalisable in an orthonormal basis), and being of rank 1 (all columns are the same), it has 0 as eigenvalue of order (n-1), and the trace which is n of order 1.

Then $J-I$ being a polynomial in J, the eigenvalues are the images of $J$'s eigenvalues, hence -1 of order n-1 and n-1 of order 1.

Conversely, if you have the previous spectrum, then the adjacency matrix of the graph G is such that there exists $O$ orthonormal matrix such that $W = O^T J O - I$.
$W$ being an adjacency matrix, it is a zero-one matrix. Hence, if we write $v_i = \sum_k O_{ki}$, we have for all $i,j$ :
$$(v_i)^2 = 1, v_iv_j\in\{0,1\}$$
The $v_i$ have the same sign, you can assume positive or take $-O$.
Then $v_i = 1$ for all $i$ and the graph is complete

Comment: I understand how to get the spectrum of the complete graph using essentially this logic. However I am not comfortable running the logic in reverse, is doing so perfectly sound?

Comment: Oh right I misread the question, sorry about that, let me update the answer

Comment: No problems, I didn't write it very clearly, I have tried to spruce up the question to be more clear.