# Let G be a graph with at most two distinct Eigenvalues. Show that G is Complete.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Here [Eigenvalues of a Complete graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423024/eigenvalues-of-a-complete-graph) it is said that a complete graph has eigenvalue n-1 with multiplicity 1 and eigenvalue -1 with multiplicity n-1. I have seen in all examples that I could come up with that a graph with at most two distinct Eigenvalues is complete. Is there a general proof for the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the graph has only two eigenvalues, the minimal polynomial of its adjacency matrix is $t^2+at+b$ for some $a$ and $b$. If $a=0$, then $A^2=-bI$ and the only 01-matrix that satisfies this is $I$ itself. So
\[
 A^2 = -aA -bI
\]
and therefore if $u\ne v$ and $(A^2)_{u,v}\ne0$, then $A_{u,v}\ne0$.
In other words if two vertices in the graph are distance two they are adjacent. It follows that a *connected graph* with only two eigenvalues is complete.

Note that two vertex-disjoint copies of $K_n$ is a graph with only two eigenvalues.

Comment: Does every matrix satisfy its minimal polynomial, like it satisfies its characteristic equation?

Comment: @user544851: yes it does, the minimal polynomial is defined as the monic polynomial of least degree satisfied by $A$.

Comment: Okay. One more question that crosses my mind is why the two eigenvalues have to be distinct?

Comment: The symmetric matrices with only one eigenvalue are scalt multiples of the identity.. (I am not really sure what you’re asking.)

Comment: The question clearly says that the graph has two distinct Eigen values. But your proof doesn't use or prove the fact that the Eigen values are distinct.

Comment: If the two eigenvalues were not distinct, the minimal polynomial would be linear, not quadratic.