# Eigenvalues of a complete connected network

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, network

The question is how to find a closed formula for the characteristic polynomial and the eigenvalues of the $N$*$N$ adjacency matrix $A$ of a fully connected network of size $N$:

$$ A =\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 
\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.$$

My attempt:

I tried to find a recursive formula for the characteristic polynomial $P(\lambda)$. It seems that:
$$P(\lambda)_{N+1} = (-\lambda)P(\lambda)_{N} - NQ_N(\lambda)$$ where $Q_N(\lambda)$ is the determinant of the following matrix:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 
\\ 1 & -\lambda & 1 & \cdots & 1
\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & -\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Again trying to find a recursion formula for $Q_N$, using gaussians elimination  I found that:
$$Q_N(\lambda) = (-1)^{N-1}(\lambda+1)^{N-1}$$ and so:
$$P(\lambda)_{N+1} = (-\lambda)P(\lambda)_{N} +(-1)^{N}N(\lambda+1)^{N-1}$$
but at this point I couldn't go on.

---

Looking for a pattern, starting from small N, it seems that the relation I'm looking for is:
$$P_N(\lambda) = (\lambda -N + 1)(\lambda+1)^{N-1}$$
but I'm not sure and it seems in discord with the previous recurrence relation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423024/eigenvalues-of-a-complete-graph

Comment: Thanks! But I would like to have a close formula for the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Isn't it just $(x-n+1)(x+1)^{n-1}$ since you know the roots (eigenvalues)?

Comment: Yes! Thanks!  but unfortunately I don’t know the “complete graphs theory” cited in the answer, so I still want an explanation using linear algebra if it is possible.

Comment: That _is_ a linear algebra explanation. It works by explicitly finding the eigenvectors. One of them is the vector of all $1$'s.